# Accessing private memebers of a class

Tags: c++

I have a class structure like this

```
class B;

class A {
  private: 
      B *b;
  public:
      A(int val) {
           b->SetVal(val);
      }
};

class B {
  private:
      int mynum;
  public:
      B();
      void SetVal(int value) {
          mynum = value;
      }
};
```

And main:

```
void main(){
  A Head(10);
}
```

This program compiles but on run-time returns an access-violation. I understand that the `mynum` in `class B` is `private` but even if I make it public it doesn't work. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should initialize `*b` and delete in `~A()`

```
class A {
  private: 
      B *b;
  public:
      A(int val) {
           b=new B();
           b->SetVal(val);
      }
      ~A()
     {
        if(b)
        {
           delete b;
           b=0;
        }
     }
};
```

Comment: I think that b=new B(); will need full class B specification which is not available in header file, but will be available if c-tor will be put in implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually pointed the `B` pointer anywhere. So when your constructor tries to do `b->SetVal(val)`, you'll probably get a memory access violation, and definitely not get well-defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the fact that `mynum`is private. You can always access the private members of a class from the methods of that class.